# Как реализовать сохранение в bundle или еще какими либо методами измененной картинки при вызове OnStop?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-bundle

Проблема заключается в следующем я делаю раскраску на андроид, но при вызове OnStop у меня появляется следующая ошибка JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!, потому что размер более 1 МБ. Подскажите какие есть еще возможности сохранить изменения в картинке, при вызове OnStop кроме как сохранения изменений в bundle.

Comment: На диск сохранять.

Comment: Т.е обычное сохранение и очистка bundle, а потом на onStart открытие этого же файла? Просто думал мб есть какие то более изящные решения.

Comment: Встречал только такое: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040399/1991579

Comment: не знаю, как по мне сохранять картинку в bundle это извращение. Самое лучше это конечно же на диск (самое надежное). Если вы хотите сохранить картинку до закрытие активити (до вызова onDestroy()) можете взглянуть на кеш, благо вариантов кеширования Android предлагает множество. Также зависит от того как вы реализовываете раскраску: например можно кешировать ваши действия и потом их восстанавливать (бредом попахивает), но задачи бывают разные. Можно преобразовывать в base64 и хранить в базе, json или если хватит места в том же bundle. всё зависит от ваших задач и желаний извращений)))